# Is it possible to return one String if the function call is in an panic::catch_unwind in rust?

Tags: rust

My code:

```
let result= panic::catch_unwind( || {
   do_olr(
      &payload_buffer[..],
      args.cmd_collect
   );
});

if !result.is_ok() {
    error!("Premature end of payload$")
}
```

I would like to keep the catch_unwind for safety reasons but still return a value.
so that there is something like this:

```
let val = do_olr(
   &payload_buffer[..],
   args.cmd_collect
);
```

is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::panic::catch_unwind` returns whatever the closure returned in case it didn't panic:

```rust
fn main() {
    let result = std::panic::catch_unwind(|| {
        println!("hello!");

        42
    });
    println!("{:?}", result);

    let result = std::panic::catch_unwind(|| {
        panic!("oh no!");
    });
    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

([Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c3c8e2a89efa4ff1e46388ce45094f6b))

This prints

```
hello!
Ok(42)
Err(Any)
```

---

> I would like to keep the `catch_unwind` for safety reasons

I don't really see how `catch_unwind` helps with safety: If you are executing unknown code, it could terminate your program in ways not catchable with `catch_unwind` [even in safe code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/fn.exit.html). There is absolutely no guarantee that `catch_unwind` will be called. `catch_unwind` provides no isolation whatsoever.